# How to pass output from one model to other Model in deep learning using Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, data-science

I want to take the output of 'model_stage_1' and concatenate it with other data as input to the other model. Below is my approach.

```
model_stage_1 = Model(inputs=[audio_input, text_input], outputs=[audio_text])

 --- some other part of the model--
audio_x2 = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=8, activation='relu')(audio_input)
audio_x2 = Dense(32)(audio_x2)

pic_x = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same")(pic_input)
pic_x = Dense(32)(pic_x)

[stage_1_output] = model_stage_1.outputs 

pic_audio_text = concatenate([stage_1_output, pic_x, audio_x2])
pic_audio_text = Dense(32)(pic_audio_text)
out = Dense(laugh_output_dim, activation='sigmoid')(pic_audio_text)

model = Model(inputs=[audio_input, pic_input, text_input], outputs=[out])
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Is this the correct way to take the output from one model and fuse it with other data?
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: two things look questionable:   (1) Why compile model_stage_1; do you plan to invoke that separately from "model"?   I'm not sure whether TF will complain.  (2) Will the "concatenate" work if text, audio and video are very different shapes?

Comment: @MarkLavin You are right. Compile step is not required. Changed in the question. Thanks for pointing it out. But fo the 2nd question, concatenate will work here as shapes are the same at the end

Comment: As I know it's the correct way. An alternative would be using keras functional API.